# Python3 mysqlclient Django mysql migrate Permission denied

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, database-migration, django-migrations

First time I tried to use Django and Mysql on Python 3. I Use mysqlclient library which is recommended by Django. But when I try to migrate, I got this error. I use OS X El Capitan and Python 3.5.1.

Here's the error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1018, "Can't read dir of './mydbname/' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)")
```

I tried `sudo python3 manage.py migrate`.

What's the problem?

Comment: You need to show your database settings.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, I did :) Problem is not on settings. It's working on Python 2.7 and MySQL-Python.